# How can I make Flask work with Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, rest, flask

I have written an API in my personal machine and I want to make it run on a remote machine.

I have used Python 3 and flask with Pycharmm without any problems in my own machine. However I connect the remote machine using ssh. So it's impossible to configure environment with an IDE.

When I type `flask --version` the output is as below:

```
Flask 0.12.2 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24)  
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Python 3 is installed. I have a choice to run the python script using `python3 service.py`. At that time I am given an error as `ImportError: No module named 'flask'`. When I use `flask run` I am given errors related to Python 2. I have used some features of Python 3 which are not included in Python 2.

How can I configure Flask to run using Python 3 in that environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pip3 install flask`. Ideally you should be doing this in a `virtual environment`. Also, you might want to look at `dockerizing` your code since it will help reduce conflict between different `python` versions.

> As an addition I have installed the pip3 using `apt-get install
>   python3-pip`

Comment: deleted comment and added answer since it worked for OP.